# ! Dimension too large

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I keep getting the error `Dimension too large` when i make my `\Desktops{80}` and my `\DTUnits{20}` however if I change my `\DTUnits{14}` it works, can someone help me please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{times,helvet,pgfplots,transparent}


%------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\letterHead

\begin{Contract}

\begin{SLAInfo}

%*******************ONLY CHANGE INFO BELOW!!!!******************


\date{27 May 2013}
\effectiveDate{1 June 2013}
\theirName{SAMWU}
\theirRep{MR. Conrad Groendevelt}
\theirPosn{Management}
\theirAddress{17 TERMO AVENUE, TEGNOPARK, STELLENBOSCH.}





\Desktops{80}
\Laptops{0}
\Macs{0}

\Servers{3}

\DTUnits{20}
\ServUnits{6}

\KM{30}


\ReportsNeededPerSite{0}





\Takeon{0}


\SLATotal{0}






%*******************ONLY CHANGE INFO ABOVE!!!!******************


\Printers{0}
\author{Mr. Alex Masters}
\ourRep{Alex Masters}
\title{\cntrctTheirName\ \textbf{- SLA}}
\docId{SLA - \cntrctTheirName}

\terms{7}
\deposit{}
\escalation{10\%}
\head

%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{PaymentSchedule}\label{payment}

The following pricing table includes once-off setup and deployment, and support.

\begin{OnceoffMonthYearPrices}{}
\priceItem{}{}{}{}


\ifnum\ecTakeon=0 %
        \priceItem{Take on Audit of all Desktop/s, Laptop/s and Sever/s}{R \pgfmathparse{int((25*\ecDesktops)+(25*\ecMacs)+(25*\ecLaptops)+(250*\ecServers)+(1000*\ecReport))}\pgfmathresult -00}{}{}
\else %
    \priceItem{Take on Audit of all Desktop/s, Laptop/s and Sever/s}{R \ecTakeon-00}{}{}
\fi



    \priceItem{}{}{}{}


\ifnum\ecDesktops=0 %
    %
\else %
%R 90 per Desktop/Laptop
    \priceItem{\mhmon of \fillinField{\bf{\ecDesktops}} x Desktop/s.}{}{}{}
\fi

%R 90 per Macbook
\ifnum\ecMacs=0 %
    %
\else %
    \priceItem{\mhmon of \fillinField{\bf{\ecMacs}} x Apple Mac/s.}{}{}{}
\fi

\ifnum\ecLaptops=0 %
    %
\else %
%R 90 per Desktop/Laptop
    \priceItem{\mhmon of \fillinField{\bf{\ecLaptops}} x Laptop/s.}{}{}{}
\fi

%R 350 per Server
\ifnum\ecServers=0 %
    %
\else %
    \priceItem{\mhmon of \fillinField{\bf{\ecServers}} x Server/s with Raid 1.}{}{}{}
\fi

    \priceItem{}{}{}{}


%-------MHSUPPORT STUFF BELOW--------------

\ifnum\ecDesktops=0 %
    %
\else %
    \priceItem{\mhsupp for \fillinField{\bf{\ecDesktops}} x Desktop/s (\ecDTUnits\ Units).}{}{}{}
\fi

\ifnum\ecMacs=0 %
    %
\else %
    \priceItem{\mhsupp for \fillinField{\bf{\ecMacs}} x Apple Mac/s (Part of Desktop Units).}{}{}
\fi

\ifnum\ecLaptops=0 %
    %
\else %
    \priceItem{\mhsupp for \fillinField{\bf{\ecLaptops}} x Laptop/s (Part of Desktop Units).}{}{}{}
\fi

%R 450 per Unit
\ifnum\ecServers=0 %
    %
\else %
    \priceItem{\mhsupp for \fillinField{\bf{\ecServers}} x Server/s with Raid 1 (\ecServUnits\ Units).}{}{}{}
\fi

    \priceItem{}{}{}{} \hline \hline


\ifnum\ecSLATotal=0 %
    \priceItem{Total}{}{R \pgfmathparse{int((90*\ecDesktops)+(90*\ecMacs)+(90*\ecLaptops)+(350*\ecServers)+(350*\ecDTUnits)+(450*\ecServUnits)+(12*\ecKM))}\pgfmathresult -00}{}\hline \hline

\else %
    \priceItem{Total}{}{R \ecSLATotal-00}{}\hline \hline
\fi

\end{OnceoffMonthYearPrices}



\end{PaymentSchedule}

%------------------------------------------------------------

\end{SLAInfo}

\end{Contract}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please reduce your example to known packages. You input of `/Tex/Permdocs/7clegal` isn't part of any TeX installation.

Answer (score 6):

This happens because the value you're trying to calculate is larger than the TeX engine can handle. For working with large numbers, use the `fpu` library. You load it with `\usetikzlibrary{fpu}`, and activate it using `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}`. The math expressions can usually remain unchanged.

It's usually a good idea to use `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}` to print the result of a calculation, instead of using `\pgfmathresult` directly. The `\pgfmathprintnumber` macro takes care of rounding values, if necessary, and can be used to format numbers consistently (think thousands and decimal separators, for example).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\Desktops{80}
\def\Laptops{0}
\def\Macs{0}    
\def\Servers{3}   
\def\DTUnits{20}
\def\ServUnits{6}    
\def\KM{30}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
\pgfmathparse{(90*\Desktops)+ (90*\Macs)+ (90*\Laptops)+ (350*\Servers)+ (350*\DTUnits)+ (450*\ServUnits)+ (12*\KM)}

Total: \pgfmathprintnumber[1000 sep=\,]{\pgfmathresult}
\end{document}
```