# Debugging Advice: Dimension too large (Need stack trace)

Tags: calculations, debugging

### Background:

I am stuck on a `"Dimension too large"` problem which is occurring during index generation.  This is a large index of links to files (along with other related information), and am sure the problem is not with the indexing packages, but in my code that adds the related information. The message I get in my actual use case is:

> ./FileName-FileName.ind:8741: Dimension too large. 
>    \pgfmath@x
>
> l.8741 ...path to file}
>                                                    \hyperpage{119}
>   ?

If I reduce the size of this index (even if it includes the offending file that was being linked to, as listed in the error message above) the problem does *not* occur.  So, it is not a problem with the file listed in the error message, but with the macros that determine which related information to add.

If I could get a stack dump and know what part of my code calls `pgfmath` before the problem occurs, then I could have some hope of determining the root of the problem.  This same code is executed 1000s of times before the problem shows up, so I can't just terminate early by putting an undefined macro in the code to do a manual trace.

---

### Sample Test Case

Although things are obvious in the "cooked" up MWE below, they are not in my actual code. 
The MWE below terminates with:

> ./TeX-SE.tex:38: Dimension too large.
>   to be read again
>     \relax  l.38 }
>         %

So, from the error message I know where the problem originates in the main source code. But form there, how do I determine where the problem lies?  Also note that the error message here gives no indication that the problem is some `pgfmath` function.

### References:

- [Origin and formation to the ERROR ‘Dimension too large’](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139883/origin-and-formation-to-the-error-dimension-too-large).
- [! Dimension too large](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118487/dimension-too-large)

### Notes:

- In the MWE below, the source of the problem is obvious and several fixes are possible. But, in my actual use case I have not yet been able to narrow down the source of a problem with a similar error message. So, this question is about *how* do I narrow down the source of the problem, *not* how do I fix this *specific* issue..

### Code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{GrillFunctions.sty}
    \newcommand*{\FunctionValue}[1]{%
        % ... lots of code ....
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\NewValue}{\arabic{MyCounter}/100}%
        \num{\NewValue}%
        % ... lots of code ....
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{GrillMacros.sty}
    \newcommand*{\DeterminePercentage}[1]{%
        % ... lots of code ....
        % ... Don't know what in here is creating the problem.
        %     Obvious given this MWE, but in actual usage not so obvious
        \FunctionValue{#1}%
        % ... lots of code ....
    }
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{GrillFunctions}
\usepackage{GrillMacros}

\newcounter{MyCounter}
\setcounter{MyCounter}{100000}


\begin{document}
\IfStrEq{\arabic{MyCounter}}{0}{%
    Value of counter is zero.%
}{%
    Value of counter is \DeterminePercentage{\arabic{MyCounter}}.%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: TeX is a macro expansion language: there is no stack trace to see. That's why building MWEs and using `\tracingall`/'marker' macros is so important in debugging TeX code. As such, perhaps all we will be able to say is that you'll have to try to isolate the conditions for the error (not an answer, clearly!).

Comment: @JosephWright: Is there a good question on here that explains where `\tracingall` gets its information from? If one could access that, then it should be possible to build a stack trace. Or perhaps I can conditionally enable `\tracingall` _after_ a certain number of iterations. I will try that...

Comment: \tracingall isn't a primitive it just sets all of texs tracing registers to their maximum values you also don't need tracingall (eg trace the paragraph breaker, probably just \tracingmacros=2

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: When I add `\tracingmacros=2` to the MWE, I don't see how to read that to find the problem. Even knowing that the problem is with `\FunctionValue` in this case and searching for it in the log file, we see that `\FunctionValue` shows up only on the lines around 870 in the log file, but there are over 2000 lines in the log file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I think it would be a useful answer to show how to use `tracingmacros=2` on the MWE and its output to determine the location of the problem.

Comment: My guess is that you are getting an overflow error in your calculation: TeX integers are limited to a maximum of 16383.

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah I think you are probably correct.

Comment: Small correction to Andrew's comment: TeX dimensions are limited to 16383.99998pt, but TeX integers are limited to 2147483647.

Comment: basically you read the log backwards starting from the error, the tracing macros output shows you the macro that was trying to assign the register then you can look back to work your way back through the expansions until you come to a top level macro you recognise

Comment: `\expandafter\def\expandafter\NewValue\expandafter {\the\numexpr \value{MyCounter}/100\relax }`, or with an `\edef`.

Comment: @jfbu: I was trying to determine the source of the problem with this question. The fixes are only possible once you narrow down in which file and approx what line the problem is on. With nested files this is not so easy.

Comment: @PeterGrill I had just read the [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194896/4686) by percusse, which led me to forget your actual question. If you agree I propose I delete my comment and this one.

Comment: For the general case see also [compiling - How to trace LaTeX errors efficiently? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125399/how-to-trace-latex-errors-efficiently)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So if I was debugging this I'd add tracing so the MWE looked like

```
\begin{document}
\tracingmacros2
\tracingassigns2
```

Then run the MWE stopping at the error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.39 }
      %
? x
No pages of output.
```

then look at the log file in an editor, starting from the error:

```
#1<-\pgfmath@operand@b 
#2<-\pgfmath@operand@a 

\pgfmath@operand@b ->100000

! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.39 }
```

so we know `\pgfmath@operand@b` being the first argument to the last macro expanded ended up being 100000 which is too large in this context. So interesting thing is where that value of 100000 came from. So simplest thing rather than trying to trace the full expansion logic is to just search backwards for 100000

It crops up in various places eg

```
{changing \pgfmath@stack@operand@top=macro:->100000}
```

but in that case it had come from

```
#1<-100000
```

ie it was the first argument to that macro, so work back to see where it came from...

```
\pgfmathresult ->100000
```

looks promising....

but keep going

```
#1<-100000/100
```

bit of a clue it was trying to work out a percentage...

```
\@arabic #1->\number #1
#1<-\c@MyCounter 
{changing \@xs@arg@i=\relax}
{into \@xs@arg@i=\long macro:->100000}
```

Hmm the 100000 is the arabic value of `MyCounter`  and there is no earlier occurrence of 100000 (because I started tracing after `begin{document}` I could have started tracing at the `\setcounter{MyCounter}{100000}` but that would be cheating:-)

So basically the log tells you that the LaTeX counter `MyCounter` was used in a calculation at a point that it had the value 100000 which is too large. At that point either you recognise where you are and what to change or you move the tracing back (and perhaps turn on `\tracingifs` or some of the other trace options and see how and why `MyCounter` got that value...

So although the log had 2500 lines, it's quite readable if you read it backwards and only read half a dozen of the lines:-)

Answer (score 9):

TeX is a macro expansion language and as such there is no stack trace: when a macro `\foo` is expanded to it's replacement text, the fact that this came from one macro rather than another or just by being part of the source directly is not recorded.  Debugging TeX issues therefore requires a different approach using the tools TeX does provide.

Probably the most common approach to finding issues it to use the macro `\tracingall`, which is available in plain TeX, LaTeX and ConTeXt. After `\tracingall` a number of registers are set which lead to TeX printing additional information in the log file. As noted in comments, the primitive setting `\tracingmacros=2\relax`, which is part of `\tracingall`, is probably the single most useful setting to employ in tracing an issue due to macro expansion. Adding either `\tracingall` or `\tracingmacros=2\relax` will potentially lead to a very long log file, which then needs to be read through by hand. As you are looking for an error, it's probably easiest to do this by searching for the error line then reading backward to see what was happening to cause it.

With more complex situations such as this one, other techniques are also helpful. One is the 'classic' of forcing TeX to pause the run by inserting some undefined control sequence (*e.g.* `\ERROR`) part-way though the source. This can help to pin down where an issue is occurring and so reduce how much tracing is needed.

With a loop situation, it's potentially useful to add some code to the loop to for example print register values to the log (*e.g.* `\immediate\write-1{Value is: \the\RegisterOfInterest}`) or to start tracing only when some condition is met (*e.g.* `\ifnum\mycount>1000 \expandafter\tracingall\fi`).

Beyond these 'standard' techniques, it usually comes down to carefully modifying the source and definitions it uses to 'pull out' the important information, then perhaps constructing some test cases and working through systematically.

---

Taking the example in the question, if I apply `\tracingmacros` just before `\IfStrEq` and turn it off after the conditional, I get a log of 14449 lines with the error on line 2066. The relevant lines just before the error read:

```
\pgfmathdivide@ #1#2->\begingroup \pgfmath@x =#1pt\relax \pgfmath@y =#2pt\relax
 \let \pgfmath@sign =\pgfmath@empty \ifdim 0pt=\pgfmath@y \pgfmath@error {You'v
e asked me to divide `#1' by `#2', but I cannot divide any number by `#2'}\fi \
afterassignment \pgfmath@xa \c@pgfmath@counta \the \pgfmath@y \relax \ifdim 0pt
=\pgfmath@xa \divide \pgfmath@x by\c@pgfmath@counta \else \ifdim 0pt>\pgfmath@x
 \def \pgfmath@sign {-}\pgfmath@x =-\pgfmath@x \fi \ifdim 0pt>\pgfmath@y \expan
dafter \def \expandafter \pgfmath@sign \expandafter {\pgfmath@sign -}\pgfmath@y
 =-\pgfmath@y \fi \ifdim 1pt>\pgfmath@y \pgfmathreciprocal@ {\pgfmath@tonumber
{\pgfmath@y }}\pgfmath@x =\pgfmath@sign \pgfmathresult \pgfmath@x \else \def \p
gfmathresult {0}\pgfmath@divide@periodtrue \c@pgfmath@counta =0\relax \pgfmathd
ivide@@ \pgfmath@x =\pgfmath@sign \pgfmathresult pt\relax \fi \fi \pgfmath@retu
rnone \pgfmath@x \endgroup
#1<-\pgfmath@operand@b
#2<-\pgfmath@operand@a

\pgfmath@operand@b ->100000

! Dimension too large.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.39 }
      %
?
```

What we see here is that TeX expands `\pgfmathdivide@` to that rather long definition with `\pgfmath@operand@b` as `#1` and `\pgfmath@operand@b` as `#2`. TeX now works through the tokens: it  begins a group (which doesn't show up in this trace: I'll come back to that), then comes to

```
\pgfmath@x =#1pt\relax
```

which is a primitive register assignment. That requires `#1` expands, so we see in the log `\pgfmath@operand@b ->100000` (remember `#1` is `\pgfmath@operand@b`). That then causes the error as the value is too big to assign to a register (the limit for a `dimen` is `16383.99998pt`, and as `pt` are used as the unit here `100000` is too  big).

If I'd also set `\tracingcommands=2\relax` I get a much longer log but a bit more info here:

```
\pgfmathdivide@ #1#2->\begingroup \pgfmath@x =#1pt\relax \pgfmath@y =#2pt\relax
 \let \pgfmath@sign =\pgfmath@empty \ifdim 0pt=\pgfmath@y \pgfmath@error {You'v
e asked me to divide `#1' by `#2', but I cannot divide any number by `#2'}\fi \
afterassignment \pgfmath@xa \c@pgfmath@counta \the \pgfmath@y \relax \ifdim 0pt
=\pgfmath@xa \divide \pgfmath@x by\c@pgfmath@counta \else \ifdim 0pt>\pgfmath@x
 \def \pgfmath@sign {-}\pgfmath@x =-\pgfmath@x \fi \ifdim 0pt>\pgfmath@y \expan
dafter \def \expandafter \pgfmath@sign \expandafter {\pgfmath@sign -}\pgfmath@y
 =-\pgfmath@y \fi \ifdim 1pt>\pgfmath@y \pgfmathreciprocal@ {\pgfmath@tonumber
{\pgfmath@y }}\pgfmath@x =\pgfmath@sign \pgfmathresult \pgfmath@x \else \def \p
gfmathresult {0}\pgfmath@divide@periodtrue \c@pgfmath@counta =0\relax \pgfmathd
ivide@@ \pgfmath@x =\pgfmath@sign \pgfmathresult pt\relax \fi \fi \pgfmath@retu
rnone \pgfmath@x \endgroup
#1<-\pgfmath@operand@b
#2<-\pgfmath@operand@a
{\begingroup}
{\dimen153}

\pgfmath@operand@b ->100000

! Dimension too large.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.40 }
      %
?
```

Notice that with command tracing TeX shows me that `\begingroup` being executed and also the fact it's trying to assign a register, which happens to be `\dimen153` in this case (you can check earlier in the log that `\pgfmath@x` is `\dimen153`).

What you'll find in this example is that as `pgf` does *lots* of work you get a *very* long log: use a proper tool to view it (something like `less` or a 'programmers editor', not something that tries to load all of the file into memory in one go).

Comment: Thanks, that is useful info. What is the difference between `\immediate\write-1` and `\typeout{}`?

Comment: `\typeout{foobar}` writes `foobar` to the log and terminal, while `\immediate\write-1{foobar}` writes `foobar` to the log only.

Comment: @PeterGrill In addition to  what Bruno says, `\typeout` is a LaTeX macro and so deals with LaTeX2e's 'protected' stuff, but it's not available with other formats. For debugging I often end up using plain or multiple formats, so using primitives tends to be handy.

Answer (score 5):

> The following explains and removes the problem of the test case. It's intended for people stumbling over the specific problem, but it's not an answer for the general case of debugging.

The mathematical engine of `pgf` sees values without units as `pt` values. Therefore, you used `100000pt` implicitly which caused the error. If you use a unit deliberatley (in my answer `sp`), the problem can be circumvented. My code gives `100` as result which you may have intended (?). Your code would have given `1000` if things would have worked. If this was really your intention, replace `65.536` by `655.36` in the code below.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{GrillFunctions.sty}
    \newcommand*{\FunctionValue}[1]{%
        % ... lots of code ....
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\NewValue}{\arabic{MyCounter}sp*65.536}% <----------
        \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]{\NewValue}%
        % ... lots of code ....
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{GrillMacros.sty}
    \newcommand*{\DeterminePercentage}[1]{%
        % ... lots of code ....
        % ... Don't know what in here is creating the problem.
        %     Obvious given this MWE, but in actual usage not so obvious
        \FunctionValue{#1}%
        % ... lots of code ....
    }
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{GrillFunctions}
\usepackage{GrillMacros}

\newcounter{MyCounter}
\setcounter{MyCounter}{100000}


\begin{document}
\IfStrEq{\arabic{MyCounter}}{0}{%
    Value of counter is zero.%
}{%
    Value of counter is \DeterminePercentage{\arabic{MyCounter}}.%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, as that is definitely a good suggestion, but that wasn't what I had intended with the question. I want to know where is the root of the problem in my actual code. From the MWE it is obvious where the problem is, so a fix can be applied. But in my actual use case, I don't know where the source of the problem is -- hence the request for debugging advice to obtain something like a stack trace.

Comment: @PeterGrill I would insert some `\show\whatever` commands at critical points of the code to encircle the problem. That's the way I find the the problematic place for most cases. It's a *poor mans* debugging but it works quite well.

Comment: Yeah, I am more than willing to use such techniques, but in this case the problem only occurs after many thousand successful execution of the same code. So problem with any such break points, is that I don't know if I am yet at the spot where the problem is. If I could narrow down the source of the problem, than such techniques would be useful.

Comment: @PeterGrill I see. If you do have a counter or something in the repetition, maybe a conditional `\show` does help (if the counter value is greater than something). But I know, it's clumsy and annoying to track down an error with that ...

Answer (score 3):

Counters are, as you can see, also limited for such computations that involve borderline numbers for TeX. Preferably switch to `fpu` library, then you won't have any problems up to 2^324. And beyond that you should use proper tools not TeX anyway :) Here is a pretty big number handled by `fpu`. Recent L3 math can also cope with these if I remember correctly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\def\FunctionValue#1{%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\NewValue}{#1/100}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,1000 sep={}]{\NewValue}%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    }
\def\DeterminePercentage#1{\FunctionValue{#1}}
\def\myval{100000000000000000000000000000000000000}

\begin{document}
    Value of counter is \DeterminePercentage{\myval}.%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The L3 FPU is IEEE754-compliant, so has no issues here provided floats are appropriate. 'Big integer' and 'big float' calcs are both doable in TeX, but as you say not necessarily recommended!

Comment: @JosephWright I meant you can't set a counter that high. But yes, I think we should promote L3 fpu better as opposed to pgfmath since it is optionally uses `fpu` libraries and it is not compatible with the drawing engine.

Comment: @percusse: Yep, already tried that before posting question, and problem still occurred. So, must be some other arithmetic issue... Wait.. I did not try setting `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}`.  I thought `\usetikzlibrary{fpu}` was sufficient.  Will try `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}`.

Comment: With `\def\myval{123456789}` I get `Value of counter is 1234560` which seems to be weird.

Comment: @jfbu Indeed. This happens when relatively distant (in terms of exponents) numbers are used. Main reason is that `fpu` convert everything to mantissa-exponent form and details are lost in the mantissa. There are a few tricks but it's not-so-nice.

Comment: @percusse is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: @jfbu Shortcoming I would say.

Comment: @percusse "shortcoming" is a nice word, a French equivalent would be very useful to me, but I don't see one offhand. It is much more neutral than "defect" for example. I will probably have some use for it in my own package documentations!