# PGFplots gets a dimension too large while reading data

Tags: pgfplots

I pieced together a PGFplots file. It worked 16 out of 18 times. The two times it didn't work the input files were very similar to the ones that worked.

Error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x
```

I tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118518/83045), and the errors became

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit
got an ill-formatted floating point number `0.0'. The unreadable part was near
'0.0'..
```

and

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again>
```

I also tried tinkering with the decimal places in the input file and the    number in `precision=3,`. What's going on? The numbers in the input are seemingly too much for TeX to handle but the other files are similar and had no problems.

The `.tex` file

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

%\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
%\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true, /pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    y tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=3,
        /tikz/.cd
    },
]
\addplot table[domain=0:360] {pgf-test-631.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The data file

```
 000.0000000000   -5217.8683723600
 015.0000000000   -5217.8697310100
 030.0000000000   -5217.8734062100
 045.0000000000   -5217.8780573800
 060.0000000000   -5217.8817718100
 075.0000000000   -5217.8830629100
 090.0000000000   -5217.8817385100
 105.0000000000   -5217.8788803300
 120.0000000000   -5217.8769672400
 135.0000000000   -5217.8778445600
 150.0000000000   -5217.8811590700
 165.0000000000   -5217.8849278400
 180.0000000000   -5217.8866359200
 195.0000000000   -5217.8849276900
 210.0000000000   -5217.8811588800
 225.0000000000   -5217.8778444900
 240.0000000000   -5217.8769672200
 255.0000000000   -5217.8788803500
 270.0000000000   -5217.8817385800
 285.0000000000   -5217.8830622800
 300.0000000000   -5217.8817716900
 315.0000000000   -5217.8780572800
 330.0000000000   -5217.8734060900
 345.0000000000   -5217.8697309200
 360.0000000000   -5217.8683723600
```

Comment: It is because of the small variation in the numbers in the second column.  Replacing `5217` in your data by `0` results in a correct compilation.  See section `2.6.2 Dimension Too Large Errors` in the `pgfplots` manual.

Comment: Using `\addplot table[domain=0:360,y expr=\thisrowno{1}+5217]` gives you a plot, but the y tick labels are near to meaningless.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is the small variation in the numbers in the second column of data, they are all `-5217.8....`.  This gives `pgfplots` problems computing the `yticks`.  The `pgfplots` manual states that there is little you can do about this, but that is not true in your case.  One way, is to read the data in shifted by `5217` and the adjust the labels afterwards.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick-5217}%
    $\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3,zerofill]{\pgfmathresult}$}]
    \addplot table[domain=0:360,y expr=\thisrowno{1}+5217]
    {pgf-test-631.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The data shifting is done by specifying that the y values should be taken from the second element of each row, and then add `5217`:

```
y expr=\thisrowno{1}+5217
```

in the `addplot table` argument.
The argument to `\thisrowno` to grad entry number `2` is the value `1` as the columns are zero indexed by default.

The label printing is then done by taking the tick value, subtracting `5217`, and then printing with the desired number formatting

```
yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick-5217}%
        $\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3,zerofill]{\pgfmathresult}$}]
```

It is important that you remove other options that affect the setting of this label.

Comment: It works now but I had to use `compat=1.13` instead of `compat=1.14`.

Comment: That reflects your `pgfplots` version.  I would suggest you update to the newest one.